# Error while adding navigation in react native project

Tags: react-native, navigation

I have a login, register and a home screen in react native. While adding navigation part in app.js , i get this error below:
React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItsK6.png)

Comment: check your exports and imports. Also please post your code in an easily reproducible manner and not as a image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'createNativeStackNavigator' instead of 'createStackNavigator'. To install it run:

```
npm install @react-navigation/native-stack
```

Inside App.js :

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
```